# Transforming Emojis from and to Unicode

Tags: r, unicode, emoji

I've extracted bunch of Facebook comments in Hebrew, but when i imported it into R, i get the following text:

```
אלוהים ישמור אתכם<U+2764><U+FE0F>
```

While i've managed to set the language correctly, is there any way to transform `<U+2764><U+FE0F>`into an emoji?

thanks

Comment: How are you extracting the comments from Facebook? How are you importing them into R? Please show some actual code. `U+2764` is `HEAVY BLACK HEART` (`❤`), and `U+FE0F` is `VARIATION SELECTOR-16` to make the heart be colored red when displayed in emoji presentation. Maybe your import does not recognize emojis?

Comment: I'm using netvizz, a facebook app that extracts facebook data. actually in utf-8 coding the heavy black heart looks ok, but after importing the file into r using 'fread' function (data.table with utf-8 encoding), it seems the emojies are transformed into the above mentioned characters.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this text appear? This kind of escaped output is what you would see from `print()`, for instance, when the string being printed is encoded in a platform-local encoding instead of Latin1 or UTF-8. Make sure the string you are reading is ACTUALLY being read as UTF-8 and is being marked as UTF-8. See `Encoding()` and `enc2utf8()`.

Comment: In the notepad++ i see the text 'God bless Israel', but if i print the specific row i get '[1] "God bless Israel\xf0\u009f\u0099\u008f"' . So the text is actually defined as UTF-8. Any ideas how to transform it to emoji?

Comment: `\xf0\u009f\u0099\u008f` is NOT proper UTF-8. The 4-byte sequence `\xf0\x9f\x99\x8f` is indeed the UTF-8 form of  (`U+1F64F PERSON WITH FOLDED HANDS`), but in your case the bytes are being interpreted individually as separate Unicode characters instead of collectively as a single Unicode character. This would happen if the bytes were being interpretted as Latin-1 instead of UTF-8, for instance.